No me funciona esta conversion de date en Django
dato = datetime.strptime(fecha, "%d de %B de %Y").date()
Error:
time data '25 de agosto de 2024' does not match format '%d de %B de %Y'
Muchas gracias a quien me pueda aclarar la duda.

El código es correcto, el problema es casi seguro que tu localizacion (al menos para las fechas) no es español y %B depende de la localización,.

esta bien tu enfoque pero el datetime no entiende el idioma.
import locale
from datetime import datetime

# Establecer la localización a español
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8')  # En sistemas Unix
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'Spanish_Spain.1252')  # En sistemas Windows

date_string= '25 de agosto de 2024'
date= datetime.strptime(fecha_cadena, '%d de %B de %Y')

print(date)


Muchas gracias problema resuelto.

Ya probada la aplicación también en windows con la modificación de la linea de esta manera locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL 'es_ES.UTF-8')

El código en general y el formato en concreto son correctos, el problema es la localización que no estará establecida en español y %B depende de ella. Es bastante probable que tengas establecidoLC_TIME=C ya que POSIX/C se considera el locale por defecto y "seguro" en general. Puedes comprobarlo desde Python con:
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME)

Usar setlocale es una opción válida, pero dos consideraciones:

El locale se cambia globalmente, esto puede tener efectos indeseados si otras partes de la app o dependencias se relacionan también con el mismo. Se puede medio paliar restaurando el locale después de hacer la conversión:
from datetime import datetime
import locale
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def set_locale(category, locale_=None):
    current_locale = locale.setlocale(category)
    try:
        yield locale.setlocale(category, locale=locale_)
    finally:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, current_locale)


fecha = '25 de agosto de 2024' 
with set_locale(locale.LC_TIME, "es_ES.utf8"):
    date = datetime.strptime(fecha, "%d de %B de %Y").date()

print(date)


El locale tiene que estar generado en el sistema anfitrión. Es decir, si tu app se ejecuta en un sistema operativo que no tiene instalado y generado el locale es_ES se producirá una excepción sin más:
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "fr_FR.utf8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.12.5/lib/python3.12/locale.py", line 615, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting



Esto es muy importante, cuando pongas tu app en produccion tienes que tener ese locale generado en el servidor, configurado en el contenedor, etc.
Estos problema hacen que usar setlocale llegue a ser bastante contraproducente en apps que tengan que soportar múltiples localizaciones.
Desconcozco si django ofrece actualmente alguna funcionalidad propia para convertir cadenas representando fechas a datetime teniendo en cuenta la localizacion del usuario, que seriá la opción ideal.
Lo que si se puede hacer en cualquier caso es usar alguna biblioteca externa que ofrezca esto, como pendulum:
>>> import pendulum

>>> pendulum.from_format(
...     "25 de agosto de 2024",
...     "DD [d][e] MMMM [d][e] YYYY",
...     locale="es"
... )
DateTime(2024, 8, 25, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))

>>> pendulum.from_format(
...     "27 août 2024",
...     "DD MMMM YYYY",
...      locale="fr"
... )
DateTime(2024, 8, 27, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))

Establecer la localización a usar para el parseo es tan simple como usar el argumento locale o pendulum.set_locale('es').
Si quieres convertir pendulum.DateTime a datetime.date puedes hacer algo como:
import datetime
import pendulum

fecha = '25 de agosto de 2024'
pendulum_dt = pendulum.from_format(
    fecha,
    "DD [d][e] MMMM [d][e] YYYY",
    locale="es"
)
date_ = datetime.date(pendulum_dt.year, pendulum_dt.month, pendulum_dt.day)


>>> date_
datetime.date(2024, 8, 25)



Gracias @FJSevilla problema resuelto.
